# How to delete a record in a Mysql DB without reload page with Codeigniter(3)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to use jquery with Codeigniter(3) to delete a record from a table in a Mysql DB. It should be a very easy operation but I'm a newbie about Codeigniter and jquery, so for this reasion I'm having some issues.

This is a part of view where I have to delere the records, in particular this is the books(libri) part:

```
<?php
echo "<table>";
echo "<tbody>";
echo "</br>";
foreach ($libri as $row):
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                </br>
                <img src="<?php echo base_url('Immagini/book.png'); ?>" />
                <a class="pdf" data-fancybox-type="iframe" rel="group" href="<?php
                    echo base_url($row['Url_suffix']) ?>"><?php echo $row['nome']; ?>
                </a>
                <a class='deleteUser' href="<?php
                    echo site_url('libro/elimina/'.$row['ID']) ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('Immagini/button_close.png'); ?>"/>
                </a>
       </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
endforeach;
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
?>
</div>
</br>
</br>
<div>
    <h3><span class="label label-success">Guide</span> </h3>
```

This is the controller(libro):

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Libro extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function elimina($libri_id) {
        $result=$this->libri->did_delete_row($libri_id);
        redirect(site_url('admin/dashboard'), 'refresh');
        //var_dump($result);
    }
}
?>
```

And this is the jquery script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".deleteUser").click(function(e){
            $this  = $(this);
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            $.get(url, function(r){
                if(r.success){
                    $this.closest("tr").remove();
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the libri.php model:

```
<?php
/* 
 * File Name: libri.php
 */
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Libri extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        //Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get_all() {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT nome, ID, Url_suffix FROM libri');
        return $query->result_array();
    }


    function get_all_api() {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM libri');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    function get_one($libro_id) {

        $this->db->where('ID',$libro_id);
        $this->db->from('libri');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->row();
        } 
        else return false;
    }


    //fetch all employee records
      function did_delete_row($id){ 
                $this->db->where('ID',$id);
                return $this->db->delete('libri');
                }
 function inserimento($data_2){ 
                return  $this->db->insert('libri',$data_2);
                }


}
?>
```

Everything also works fine without the jquery script, I mean the page is reloaded by itself and then the the row is gone. While , with the jquery script, the page is not reloaded by itself but the "row" is still there. If I reaload the page, then the record is definately deleted.

What I'm making wrong?

Comment: Open up your javascript console in the browser and check for any errors.

Comment: @Matt I have no errors.

Comment: Where is the model class?

Comment: @Borgboy I edit the question with the model class (libri).

Comment: Thanks, in your constructor, be sure to load the database after you call parent::__construct(); $this->load->database();

Comment: @Borgboy I don't get what you say me. Please, can you explain me.

Answer (score 0):

because param $libri_id is null

```
site_url('libro/elimina/'.$row['ID'])

public function elimina($libri_id) {
     $result=$this->libri->did_delete_row($libri_id);
     redirect(site_url('admin/dashboard'), 'refresh');
}
```

try this (use segment)

```
public function elimina() {
     $libri_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
     $result=$this->libri->did_delete_row($libri_id);
     redirect(site_url('admin/dashboard'), 'refresh');
}
```

reference : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: Unfortunately , I am still in the same situation , it deletes the line only after you have updated the page

Comment: How could be `$libri_id` null if after the page is realoaded the record is gone? It does not mean that the parameter is right?

Comment: @WRDev  ellislab is old user guide location new location for old and new doc's now here http://www.codeigniter.com/docs